# How to get bit values of a character or number

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

I want to know the bit values or say binary values in a character.
for example 
for a binary value is 01100001 i want to store each '0' and '1' in an array! plz tell me how to access it bitwise.

Comment: Storing the bits of something in an array is usually a sign of a bad plan. Not always, but usually. What are you planning to use this for?

Comment: You can get the bits of *anything* by using the bitwise shift and bitwise and operators. However, you might first want to [read about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and tell us *why* you want to do it.

Comment: You can iterate the length (sizeof(char)) of the char while shifting and storing the results in an array

Comment: i want to add all the bit values and find an avg. but i don't know how to access...

Comment: if u need an AVG u can skip the array and just count the 0s ans 1s  with two ints

Comment: So you want to count the bits that are one? (and then maybe divide by something) See, storing them in an array was a bad plan. Instead, see [popcnt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Comment: @RotemVaron rather `CHAR_BIT` in case `char` is not 8 bits long.

Comment: An average of *what*? The number of `1` bits? The number of `0` bits? None of those will really tell you anything about a character or a string, so please tell us why you want this.

Comment: i just want to know how to access 1's and 0's in a char. and then calculate the avg. i don't want to store it in any array!! just how to access bitwise

Comment: And regarding the comment from @TheParamagneticCroissant, sizeof(char)` multiplied by `8` will not work, as `sizeof(char)` is specified to always return `1` no matter the number of bits in a `char`. And besides, the number of bits in a `char` doesn't have to be a multiple of `8` which make using `sizeof` moot anyway.

Comment: How does "i don't want to store it in any array!!" rhyme with the original "i want to store each '0' and '1' in an array!"? Is the number of exclamation marks significant?

Comment: OP has told us "I want to store each '0' and '1' in an array", and then "I want to add all the bit values and find an avg", and then contradicts with "I don't want to store it in any array". So it's back to @Joachim Pileborg's comment about the XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
#define N  8

//...

char c = '\x61';
int b[N] = { 0 };
size_t  i = N;

for ( unsigned char ch = c; ch; ch >>= 1 )
{
    b[--i] = ch & 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Vlad from Moscow's answer and OP's latest requirement to find the average bit value

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char ch, c = '\x61';
    double tot = 0;

    for (ch = c; ch; ch >>= 1)
        tot += (ch & 1);
    printf ("Average bit value is %f\n", tot / 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what i was looking for the whole time. Appreciated.